# can't get rid of the keyboard delay

Tags: actionscript-3

Edit: I should probably specify that I am new to flash

I've been trying to remove the keyboard delay but for some reason the delay is still here with this code and I can't figure out why:

```
var Keys = [];
stage.addEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_DOWN, function(e:KeyboardEvent){
    Keys[e.keyCode] = true;
});
stage.addEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_UP, function(e:KeyboardEvent){
    Keys[e.keyCode] = false;
});

stage.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, update);

[...]

function update(e:Event){
    if(Keys[39]){
        peg.x+=2;
    }
    if(Keys[37]){
        peg.x-=2;
    }
}
```

it looks like the values of the array are going back to false constantly, but I'm really not sure

edit: this is the entire code:

```
var rectangle:Shape = new Shape;
var nbRectangleWidth = 10;
var nbRectangleHeight = 7;
var rectMargin:int = (stage.stageWidth - (nbRectangleWidth*30))/2;

var Keys = [];
stage.addEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_DOWN, function(e:KeyboardEvent){
    Keys[e.keyCode] = true;
});
stage.addEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_UP, function(e:KeyboardEvent){
    Keys[e.keyCode] = false;
});

stage.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, update);

function initGame(){
    for(var rectY=0; rectY<nbRectangleHeight; rectY++){
        for(var rectX=0; rectX<nbRectangleWidth; rectX++){
            rectangle.graphics.beginFill(0xFFFFFF);
            rectangle.graphics.drawRect(
                rectMargin+(rectX*30),
                10+(rectY*15),
                25, 10
            );
            rectangle.graphics.endFill();
            addChild(rectangle);
        }
    }
};
initGame()

function update(e:Event){

    ball.x = peg.x;
    ball.y = peg.y - peg.height/2 - ball.height/2;

    if(Keys[39]){
        peg.x+=2;
    }
    if(Keys[37]){
        peg.x-=2;
    }
}
```

Comment: What makes you think that the values go back to false? Did you try to trace the values or use the debugger?

Comment: I've just tried `trace(Keys[e.keyCode]);` and it's always true

Comment: What do you mean by delay?

Comment: when you hit a key to move, the square move once, stops, and then moves again

Comment: Your script works. Are there other ENTER_FRAME-functions?

Comment: nope, I can show the entire script if you want

Comment: I've added the entire code in the post

Comment: I've just traced `Keys[39]` and it says says both true and undefined when I hit the key to move